# gets() seems to store some garbage string

Tags: c

I wish to enter strings with spaces. I used gets(), already taking care of the newline character [using `while( (c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != '\0');` ] that may create problem. But the first gets() inputs some stray characters! Also, if i use `scanf( "%[^\n]s", a)` instead of `gets()` some random string is stored ! can someone help me find out why?

here's the code :

```
printf(" \n Enter the string");
while( (c =getchar()) != '\n' && c != '\0');
gets(a); // some garbage string is stored in a....if i replace it with scanf()...then                    also garbage string is stored 

printf(" \n The ENTERED  string is %s", a);


printf("\n Enter the substring to be extracted (max 20)  ");
while( (c =getchar()) != '\n' && c != '\0');
gets(sub);
```

Comment: `gets()` is dangerous and error prone. It should not be used. They even removed it in the latest C standard. Use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: Your code doesn't show the declaration and initialisation of the variable `a`, so there's no way to see why your code is wrong. (other than the `gets` vs `fgets` issue already mentioned by others)

Comment: i declared both strings as character arrays !

Answer (score 1):

This works for me; I have used a short buffer to check that nothing bad happens if the input string overflows the input buffer (the overflow is buffered by `stdin` to the next call to `fgets`, as expected from a stream).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char a[32];
    for (;;) {
            printf("Enter the string:\n");
            fgets(a, sizeof(a), stdin);
            strtok(a, "\r\n");
            printf("The entered string is '%s'\n", a);
    }
}
```